# WebSocket Library

Tags: c++, api, websocket

I want to access a WebSocket API using C++ on Linux. I've seen different librarys (like *libwebsockets* or *websocketpp*), but I'm not sure which I should use. The only thing I need to do is **connect to the API and receive data** to a string. So I'm looking for a very **basic** and simple solution, nothing too complex. Maybe someone has already made experience with a WebSocket library?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For a high-level API, you can use `ws_client` from the [cpprest](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk) library {it wraps [websocketpp](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp)}.

A sample application that runs against the [echo server](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cpprest/ws_client.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace web;
using namespace web::websockets::client;

int main() {
  websocket_client client;
  client.connect("ws://echo.websocket.org").wait();

  websocket_outgoing_message out_msg;
  out_msg.set_utf8_message("test");
  client.send(out_msg).wait();

  client.receive().then([](websocket_incoming_message in_msg) {
    return in_msg.extract_string();
  }).then([](string body) {
    cout << body << endl; // test
  }).wait();

  client.close().wait();

  return 0;
}
```

Here `.wait()` method is used to wait on tasks, however the code can be easily modified to do I/O in the asynchronous way.

Comment: Thank you! Does it also support subscribtion to a channel?

Comment: And also, it says **Microsoft project** on their page. So it won't work on Linux systems probably?

Comment: It is pretty solid and runs on Windows, OS X, iOS, and **Linux (including Android)**. As a matter of fact, I coded and run this sample on Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Project Wiki has info on building the lib on various platforms, e.g. [How to build for Linux](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/How-to-build-for-Linux).

Comment: Is there a WebSocket Server at this library? Or just client websocket?

Comment: CppRestSdk is in maintainance mode, and not recommended for new projects as of now.