# Is it possible to connect to node. js websocket server with c++ client

Tags: javascript, c++, websocket

I have created websocket server and client with help of following link.

https://github.com/websockets/ws

It works fine but I also would like to connect to my node.js server with c++ client. Is it possible ?

Comment: Recommend rewording this question. Currently it reads as a request for an offsite tutorial, and such requests are off topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible, WebSocket is a  standardized protocol by the IETF. You just need a WebSocket Library for c++.

For example:
[WebSocket Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34423092/websocket-library)